# How can an External Task Handler set a variable and let subsequent activity read this variable?

Tags: micronaut, camunda

I have a very simple three step workflow in which all steps are handled by external task handlers.

[image: simple process]

In the first step *Erstelle Rechnung* (Create invoice) the external task handler creates a PDF document and adds on completion to the process.

```java
externalTaskService.complete(externalTask, Map.of("pdf", "pdf byte array");
```

As the screenshot illustrates below the variable pdf has been written to the activity *Erstelle Rechnung*.

[image: Variable is available after completion]

Unfortunately the variable is not visible for the subsequent activity *Bestätigungsemail an Mitglied schicken*.

[image: Var not visible]

Can anybody help me on this. What am I missing? Should the variable be visible in the hierarchy of the subsequent activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What problem you get with this - a Nullpointer when trying the use the variable *pdf*?

Because not seeing the variable when you highlight the activity does not mean that it is not there. As your screenshot shows - pdf is in the correct scope (if your process is 'Ticketbestellung';)), so it should be available for the next External Tasks.

My guess is that you have a problem on how you fetch the task. (Maybe you can add this to your question)

Another point that is strange to me, is how you provide your file as a variable. I think it should be something like this

```
  FileValue variableValue = Variables.fileValue(filename).file(byteContent).mimeType(mimeType).create();
  Variables.createVariables().putValue("pdf", variableValue);
```

Comment: You're are right. The variable is present. I was obviously to tired to read the error message correctly. It wasn't a nullpointer exception but a class cast exception. Thank you for pointing me the way to work with typed variables. much appreciated.